# Android WebView SSL handshake failed

Tags: ssl-certificate, android-webview, chromium, handshake, android-security

**I know this question has been asked a lot of times, I tried all solutions, but no one didn't fit my case.**

I have news feed in my app, when I clicked on some piece of news - it's open in WebView. Sometimes it gives an error(but still opening site):

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
```

News are loaded by Newscatcher API and OkHttpClient3:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://free-news.p.rapidapi.com/v1/search?")
                    .get()
                    .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key")
                    .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host")
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

What I've found and tried:

- Network Security Configuration - not possible, news sources changes dynamically, I can't include all domains.
- Ignore SSL error - not possible, the app will be uploaded to Play Store.
- onReceivedSslError and show dialog to make the user responsible for this - I don't think this is a good idea at all.

So, what I can implement in my case to solve this problem?